# Match two files and keep some variables

Tags: spss

I have two files with same ID variable, so I want to match them with the MATCH FILES command, but I want to keep all the variables from the first file and just some from the other one. Thing is, I don't want to type every variable from the first file, but the subcommand KEEP ALL seems it's not working. Here my syntax and the error message:

```
GET FILE='C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Households.sav'.
SORT CASES BY ID (A).

GET FILE='C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Adults.sav'.
SORT CASES BY ID (A).

MATCH FILES
/FILE=*
/KEEP ALL
/FILE='C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Households.sav'
/BY ID
/KEEP PV1 PV2 PV3 PV4.
EXECUTE.

SAVE OUTFILE
'C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\matchHouseholdsAdults.sav'.
```

> Subcommands are out of order.  All the FILE, TABLE, RENAME and IN subcommands must precede all other kinds of subcommands.  Syntax checking begins with the next slash.

Thanks, fellows.

Answer (score 0):

From the CSR:

DROP and KEEP must follow all FILE, TABLE, and RENAME subcommands.

You can use /DROP after the second FILE subcommand to ge rid of unwanted variables in the second file.  If there are duplicate names, the first FILE content take priority.

Comment: So I can't use it in the first FILE expression... a pitty. To get rid of the variables I don't want in the second file is problematic as well, there are a lot.